# MySQL Date before year 1000 allowed?

Tags: mysql, datetime, range, mysql-workbench

I read from the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) that years before 1000 are not allowed in the DATETIME data type:

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

Can somebody please explain to me how this code works, then:

```
CREATE TABLE testing_dates(
    test_date DATETIME
);                           

INSERT INTO testing_dates
VALUES ('0001-12-22 12:12:12');
```

Comment: Did you ensure the date is actually stored as given after insertion?

Answer (score 3):

On the same page you link to, it says:

> For the DATE and DATETIME range descriptions, “supported” means that although earlier values might work, there is no guarantee.

I'd interpret this to mean that they have software tests for the supported range, but not for values outside the range.